# Rotate point in 3D - AxisAngleRotation3D

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I have three points in 3D: 
A, B, C, this points makes plane (it is not orthogonal to any axis)
and I would like to rotate point B around "point C" actually
kind of axis through C which is perpendicular to A,B,C plane.
So I am looking for B' coordinates (B' lies in the same plane as the other points)
As you can see, the radius is distance between B and C.

I am able to do it in 2D but in 3D geometry I am kind of lost.
Effort to search formula or figure out calculate was unsuccessful.

I was thinking about `RotateTransform3D` and `AxisAngleRotation3D` functions,
but I am not able to specify the axis around which to rotate - firts parameter for `AxisAngleRotation3D`.

Any help or reference is welcome, thank you

[image: problem description]

Comment: _[Quaternions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.quaternion(v=vs.110).aspx)_ might be the way to go

Comment: in 3D you cant rotate point around point without axis because of the third dimension. to witch direction you want to rotate? the axis specifies that. Do you know the vector `a` you have shown in image? if you just want to move the point like shown in image you can rotate around `Vector(0,0,1)` .(note that the vector always should be normalized) but if you want to rotate in whole 3d space you must at least specify vector `a` to get the rotation axis. can you tell what are you trying to do? you just want to rotate a point or you are using this somewhere in your program?

Comment: Vector(0,0,1) does not work, i think it is rotation around Z axis. I would like to use it in program - not to animate it, just recalculate points coordinates. I need to shift point B along a circular path. In 2D it is around point C, In 3D it is around line which is perpendicular to the plane determined by A,B,C points. And B is in distance CB - turning radius. I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction, however I am not able to determine this perpendicular vector.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary _"in 3D you cant rotate point around point without axis because of the third dimension"_ - Incorrect. One merely rotates in model space where the origin will be (0,0,0), model space equivalent of **C** in other words. The problem the OP is describing is typical in **joints** in a 3D model, say an elbow.  Pretty sure there are plenty of games out there with 3D elbows.  OP has already described what the axis will be.